# Wixtoolset - Support for Ratina display in themes for Logo & LogoFile

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I have built a setup in VS 2019 with WiX Toolset 3.11.1.2318
I am using LogoFile & LogoSide which works fine in Windows 10. But if the setup is used on Ratina display, image doesn't appear crisp. Is there any way I can use 2x version of these files in the setup? Right now, if I use 2x version of images, they will cut in setup. It's used like this

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkSidebarLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LogoFile="Resources/Sidebar.png" ThemeFile="Resources/ClassicTheme.xml" LocalizationFile="Resources/ClassicTheme.wxl" LicenseUrl="" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

Comment: That's a known bug in Wix 3 and reportedly fixed in Wix 4, but its still in development https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally upgraded to WIX 4 and this issue was resolved.